# Jquery sortable / scrollable tabs jumping

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, jquery-ui-sortable

I have some sortable / scrollable tabs but the sibling tabs keep jumping when I start sorting.

The axis is set to 'x' yet when sorting you can slightly drag up and down, which is where you will see the jumping.

Normally I would fix this by setting `float: left;` but this causes each tab to be in it's own "row" somehow.

How can I stop this "jumping" issue in sortable / scrollable tabs?

```js
$('.data_tab_tabs').sortable({
  items: '.data_tab',
  axis: 'x',
  containment: 'parent',
  helper: 'clone',
  appendTo: 'parent',
  forcePlaceholderSize: true,
  tolerance: 'pointer',
});
```

```css
.data_tab_container {
  width: 500px;
  height: fit-content;
  position: relative;
}

.data_tab_tabs {
  height: 40px;
  width: fit-content;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.data_tab {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: inline-block;
  width: fit-content;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  background: #f1f3f6;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  margin-right: 4px;
  /*   float: left; */
  font-weight: 600;
}

.data_tab * {
  display: inline-block;
}

.data_tab.active_data_tab {
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}


/* width */

.data_tab_tabs::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 6px !important;
}


/* Track */

.data_tab_tabs::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent !important;
}


/* Handle */

.data_tab_tabs::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #ddd !important;
  border-radius: 3px;
}


/* Handle on hover */

.data_tab_tabs::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #ccc !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="data_tab_container">
  <div class="data_tab_tabs">
    <div class="data_tab active_data_tab" data-tab="headers" data-level="1">Here is something</div>
    <div class="data_tab" data-tab="body" data-level="1">Here is something else</div>
    <div class="data_tab" data-tab="footers" data-level="1">Here is something else again</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to contain the element `.data_tab_tabs` within another div which I named `.data_tab_scroll`.

I had to do quite a few css changes to get this to work correctly without breaking the way the tabs looked normally or when sorting.

With these changes another issue occurred which was that the sortable placeholder width would only be `1px` wide when the scroll bar was visible. To fix this I needed `.data_tab_tabs` to have `width: fit-content` and for `.data_tab_scroll` to have `width: 100%;`. There is a question related to this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28676818/horizontal-jquery-sortable-list-placeholder-width-is-incorrect-in-ie11-when-scr)

Snippets here still have the original issue, and so does Internet Explorer.

You can find a working example in my [codepen](https://codepen.io/Souleste/pen/dyPWrjZ)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `float:left;` will fix your sorting problem but it will open another problem where 3rd tab goes in new line.

It's because there is not enough space for 3rd tab. If you remove `width: 500px;` from `.data_tab_container` style than you will see its working fine.

See the Snippet below:

```js
$('.data_tab_tabs').sortable({
  items: '.data_tab',
  axis: 'x',
  containment: 'parent',
  helper: 'clone',
  appendTo: 'parent',
  forcePlaceholderSize: true,
  tolerance: 'pointer',
});
```

```css
.data_tab_container {
  /*width: 500px;*/
  height: fit-content;
  position: relative;
}

.data_tab_tabs {
  height: 40px;
  width: fit-content;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.data_tab {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: inline-block;
  width: fit-content;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  background: #f1f3f6;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  margin-right: 4px;
  float: left;
  font-weight: 600;
  
}

.data_tab * {
  display: inline-block;
}

.data_tab.active_data_tab {
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}


/* width */

.data_tab_tabs::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 6px !important;
}


/* Track */

.data_tab_tabs::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent !important;
}


/* Handle */

.data_tab_tabs::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #ddd !important;
  border-radius: 3px;
}


/* Handle on hover */

.data_tab_tabs::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #ccc !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="data_tab_container">
  <div class="data_tab_tabs">
    <div class="data_tab active_data_tab" data-tab="headers" data-level="1">Here is something</div>
    <div class="data_tab" data-tab="body" data-level="1">Here is something else</div>
    <div class="data_tab" data-tab="footers" data-level="1">Here is something else again</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update 2**

Have fixed it by adding `1px` of height in placeholder (which jQuery adds when you start drag). I think its an open bug in jQuery..

here is a fix

```
.ui-sortable-placeholder {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1px;
}
```

See the Snippet below:

```js
$('.data_tab_tabs').sortable({
  items: '.data_tab',
  axis: 'x',
  containment: 'parent',
  helper: 'clone',
  appendTo: 'parent',
  forcePlaceholderSize: true,
  tolerance: 'pointer',
  start: function(event, ui) { 
  ui.placeholder.html('&nbsp;'); 
 }
});
```

```css
.data_tab_container {
  width: 500px;
  height: fit-content;
  position: relative;
}

.data_tab_tabs {
  height: 55px; /* changin height from 40px to 55px */
  width: fit-content;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.data_tab {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: inline-block;
  width: fit-content;
  /*height: 100%;*/
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  background: #f1f3f6;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  margin-right: 4px;
  /*   float: left; */
  font-weight: 600;
}

.data_tab * {
  display: inline-block;
}

.data_tab.active_data_tab {
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

.ui-sortable-placeholder {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1px;
}


/* width */

.data_tab_tabs::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 6px !important;
}


/* Track */

.data_tab_tabs::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent !important;
}


/* Handle */

.data_tab_tabs::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #ddd !important;
  border-radius: 3px;
}


/* Handle on hover */

.data_tab_tabs::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #ccc !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="data_tab_container">
  <div class="data_tab_tabs">
    <div class="data_tab active_data_tab" data-tab="headers" data-level="1">Here is something</div>
    <div class="data_tab" data-tab="body" data-level="1">Here is something else</div>
    <div class="data_tab" data-tab="footers" data-level="1">Here is something else again</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is not the issue, when you begin sorting you will see that the tabs move up and down on the y-axis... I have a width set in place to replicate a container where the tabs would overflow, needing a scrollbar.

Comment: @Souleste please test it again. I have modified the answer

Comment: @Souleste did you check the answer?

Comment: Yes, doesn't seem to be working in my [codepen](https://codepen.io/Souleste/pen/dyPWrjZ).

Comment: I have fixed it using jQuery..It seems like CSS is not working in codepen.. So I have added alternative. You can test it [here](https://codepen.io/nimittshah/pen/PowJOGb)

Comment: Yes, it does work, but I would rather not alter the way the tabs or container "look." In your example there is now a lot of space between the scroll bar and the tabs.